# NullPointerException with getMethod()

Tags: java

This is a continuation of a previous question I had asked. I seem to be getting `NullPointerException` when calling a `public static void main` method from my Server.class.

This is my Server.class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   try {
    //what happens here is that I open up a socket and start listening
    }
    catch (Exception X) {System.out.println(X);}
}
```

This is my runServer method in another class:

```
public static void runServer() throws Exception{

    File sourceFile = new File("/Users/Joel/NetbeansProjects/FYP/src/ui_v2/Server.java");
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileMgr = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
    fileMgr.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File("/Users/Joel/NetbeansProjects/FYP/src/ui_v2")));

    compiler.getTask(null, fileMgr, null, null, null, 
            fileMgr.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(sourceFile)));
    fileMgr.close();

    try {
        Class params[] = {};
        Object paramsObj[] = {};
        Class thisClass = Class.forName("ui_v2.Server");
        Method thisMethod = thisClass.getMethod(null, params);//this is the line where the exception is thrown
        thisMethod.invoke(thisClass, paramsObj);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

This is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.searchMethods(Class.java:2995)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)
at ui_v2.GenerateChat.runServer(GenerateChat.java:354)
at ui_v2.GenerateChat.Btn_ConfirmActionPerformed(GenerateChat.java:230)
at ui_v2.GenerateChat.access$000(GenerateChat.java:26)
at ui_v2.GenerateChat$1.actionPerformed(GenerateChat.java:129)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have debugged my Server.class and I don't think the `NullPointerException` is thrown from there. Could anyone tell me where it went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) can be really helpful. :) `Throws: NullPointerException - if name is null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter in `getMethod` should be them method name, but you're having a `null` there.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
Method thisMethod = thisClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
String[] args = {};
thisMethod.invoke(null, (Object) args);
```

Comment: I have tried that. But because the method I'm calling is a `public static void main` in that Server.class, the first parameter should be null right?

Comment: @JoelSeah In the `invoke` method, the first parameter may be `null` for a static method invocation. In `getMethod`, the first parameter is the method name, in this case: `"main"`.

Comment: If i put `"main"` as my first parameter, I get a `NoSuchMethodException`. But that method does exists as shown in my `Server.class`.

Comment: @JoelSeah your `Class[] params` is also empty. There is nothing correct about your method  call.

Comment: @JoelSeah You can try printing the values from `thisClass.getDeclaredMethods()` to see that the method actually exists.

Answer (score 5):

```
thisClass.getMethod(null, params);
```

`getMethod()` allows finding a method of a class with a given name. You're passing null for the name. That can't possibly work. No method has a null name.

Read the javadoc of `getMethod()` carefully, and pay attention to what the two arguments are meant to be. `main()` is not the same method as `main(String[] args)`.

Comment: Note, `params` is also empty, so this still won't work.

Comment: @BoristheSpider my answer just signals the cause of the exception to the OP. I left the finding of the solution as an exercise. Other answers provide the answer (but the OP didn't read them carefully)...

Answer (score 3):

```
thisClass.getMethod(null, params);
```

Please go through the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)). It clearly specifies that the name should not be null.

```
Throws:
NoSuchMethodException - if a matching method is not found or if the name is "<init>"or "<clinit>".
NullPointerException - if name is null
```

Comment: If i do this `thisClass.getMethod("main",params)`, I get a `NoSuchMethodException`. But there is indeed a `public static void main(String[] args)` method in my Server.class as shown.

Comment: @JoelSeah what does the main method take as argument? Does it take nothing?

Comment: Note, `params` is also empty, so this still won't work.